# Can/Should I create a owl/rdfs class that would have only 1 instance

Tags: rdf, owl, rdfs

I have a domain of educational institutes, where `institutes` would be recognized by `authority`. There are only 2 `authorities` with no specific restrictions or properties as of now. Should I create two `sub-classes` with only one `instance` each or should I create only one `class` with two `instances`?

Comment: Well, how does it influence your further usage of the ontology? I mean, you are the only person that knows it, and from my point of view it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice depends on how you foresee the ontology being used. Are there substantial differences between the authorities? Do these authorities also represent categories that might have subcategories?

At the moment you might have only one instance for each class; is this necessarily always the case, or more instances might appear in the future? The answer to these questions should drive your choice on whether the authorities should be individuals or classes.

My view, from the content of your question, is that they should be individuals.